# How to generate a dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays

I have to generate a dynamic menu to fetch data from database and store result in the dynamic array. How to achieve this in php?

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are dynamic by default in PHP, just add more items to it. As shown in this example (assuming the database is MYSQL):

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
$menu_array = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $menu_array[$i] = $row['menu'];
    $i++;
}
```

Now `$menu_array` contains all the menu elements you fetched from the database.