# dynamic menu generation in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to generate an dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081108/how-to-generate-an-dynamic-array)

how to generate an dynamic menu which have submenu so on which have store in database and on click show submenu. Please help me i am an fresher php developer.

Comment: Duplicate of question asked by same user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081324/dynamic-menu-generation-in-php

Comment: @Joe: wrong link, question id of duplicate is 2081108

Comment: Actually, the duplicate is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081108/how-to-generate-an-dynamic-array

Comment: Hah! @streetparade sadly no. @Jørn knows what I mean!

Comment: @streetparade Joe is not drunk, there is really an infinite recursion of a question duplicating itself! I'm stuck in an endless loop clicking his link!

Comment: Where is the term 'fresher' from?

Comment: It's a British English (at least) word for someone who is new to university.

Comment: @Joe Interesting, thankyou. I've always heard it used as freshman in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog article which describes it well: http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/317/formatting-a-multi-level-menu-using-only-one-query.html Then you just use [CSS](http://google.com/search?q=css+suckerfish+dropdown) to show/hide submenus.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first create the tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE `dyn_menu` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `link_url` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#',
  `parent_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;


Prepare your DB

$sql = "SELECT id, label, link_url, parent_id FROM dyn_menu ORDER BY parent_id, id ASC";
$items = mysql_query($sql);
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($items)) {
    if ($obj->parent_id == 0) {
        $parent_menu[$obj->id]['label'] = $obj->label;
        $parent_menu[$obj->id]['link'] = $obj->link_url;
    } else {
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['parent'] = $obj->parent_id;
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['label'] = $obj->label;
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['link'] = $obj->link_url;
        $parent_menu[$obj->parent_id]['count']++;
    }
}
mysql_free_result($items);


Write The Function


function dyn_menu($parent_array, $sub_array, $qs_val = "menu", $main_id = "nav", $sub_id = "subnav", $extra_style = "foldout") {
    $menu = "<ul id=\"".$main_id."\">\n";
    foreach ($parent_array as $pkey => $pval) {
        if (!empty($pval['count'])) {
            $menu .= "  <li><a class=\"".$extra_style."\" href=\"".$pval['link']."?".$qs_val."=".$pkey."\">".$pval['label']."</a></li>\n";
        } else {
            $menu .= "  <li><a href=\"".$pval['link']."\">".$pval['label']."</a></li>\n";
        }
        if (!empty($_REQUEST[$qs_val])) {
            $menu .= "<ul id=\"".$sub_id."\">\n";
            foreach ($sub_array as $sval) {
                if ($pkey == $_REQUEST[$qs_val] && $pkey == $sval['parent']) {
                    $menu .= "<li><a href=\"".rebuild_link($sval['link'], $qs_val, $sval['parent'])."\">".$sval['label']."</a></li>\n";
                }
            }
            $menu .= "</ul>\n";
        }
    }
    $menu .= "</ul>\n";
    return $menu;
}
```

Thats it have fun